# Return node on node margin click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, click

Having this code, where each P tag is separated by margin:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
p {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem 2
  </p>
</div>
```

When I capture the click event in between the P tags, the returned node is DIV. How can I return P tag when P tag margin is clicked? I'm not allowed to change margins to paddings, which would be an easy solution.

Comment: It seems impossible using `margin` without some javascript hacks. It might be an XY problem. Why can't you use `padding` here?

Comment: `margin` isn't considered as part of the element, therefore no events are fired when it's interacted with. You can see the same issue in this demo, where the `:hover` doesn't fire until you've over the border/content of the element, not the padding: https://jsfiddle.net/su4ewqkg/. To do what you need will require you to change the HTML and/or CSS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Margin not being a part of element, yet being set on element (in CSS) is so counter-intuitive.

Comment: Adjacent margins collapse so its unclear which `p` tag should be clicked anyway https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_box_model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of pseudo-elements, such as – in the example below – the `::before`, positioned with a negative inset:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

p {
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  isolation: isolate;
  position: relative;
}

p::before {
  background-color: transparent;
  content: '';
  inset: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem 2
  </p>
</div>
```

There is still a (small) gap between the two elements' `::before`, but that can be adjusted by expanding the pseudo-elements.

Comment: I was just thinking about using some pseudo-element shenanigans with negative margins etc. This is way better!

Comment: A side effect is the `::before` blocking the interactive elements (cannot select the texts etc.) but it can be solved with `z-index` or `translateZ` etc.

Comment: @Hao: I can't believe I forgot to add that (I thought about it when I started writing the answer, but I got distracted and - when I came back - I'd clearly forgotten about it). Silly me.